Python - Cropping a Screenshot with PIL of an object found with Selenium, regardless of monitor size
I am using python and selenium in writing a program to automate a report creation. This program has to be portable and scalable — others will need to be able to use it on their own laptops or desktop monitors. As a result, I need to be able to capture and crop screenshots of a specific object on a page. Specifically, it screenshots three rows (grouped together), where the height of the three rows is the height of the  tag that I find, and the width of it is the width of the  tag that I find.
Here is what I have tried:
    #fullscreen window

    driver.fullscreen_window()


    #find correct set of rows containing user input date

    tgtElement = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//a[contains(text(), '" + userDate + "')]"))

    #get the y value

    location = tgtElement.location

    size = tgtElement.size

    yVal = location.get("y")

 

    #scroll to correct row

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, " + str(yVal - 150) + ");")

    #get size of screen as reference, specifically height

    window_handle = FindWindow(None, "myWindow")

    window_rect = GetWindowRect(window_handle)

    windowHeight = window_rect[3]

    #take screenshot of the whole screen

    driver.save_screenshot(pngLocation)

    im = Image.open(pngLocation)

    # -2 to get the second to last instance of the row span.

    # obtains the proper element

    boxElement = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td[rowspan = '3']")[-2].rect

    # get dimensions of the three rows combined

    rowHeight = boxElement.get("height")

    rowXPos = boxElement.get("x")

    rowYPos = boxElement.get("y")

    boxElement = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr").rect

    #get the width of the full row

    rowWidth = boxElement.get("width")

    #get dimensions of the whole webpage

    bodyElement = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "html[lang='en']").rect

    bodyHeight = bodyElement.get("height")

    bodyWidth = bodyElement.get("width")

    #return the ratio to find where the edges of the box are relative to the the window

    relativeRight = float(rowXPos+rowWidth) / float(bodyWidth)

    relativeLeft = float(rowXPos) / float(bodyWidth)

    #attempts to account for the fact that the length of the webpage may be less than the length of the weekend

    if bodyHeight < windowHeight:

        relativeTop = float((windowHeight -rowYPos)) / float(windowHeight)

        relativeBottom = float((windowHeight -rowYPos) + rowHeight) / float(windowHeight)

    else:

        relativeTop = float((windowHeight - (bodyHeight-rowYPos))) / float(windowHeight)

        relativeBottom = float((windowHeight - (bodyHeight-rowYPos)) + rowHeight) / float(windowHeight)

 

    print(str(bodyElement))

    width, height = im.size

    print(str(im.size))

    # left = (width - distFromRight) - 75

    # right = (width - distFromRight) + 1100

    # top = (height - distFromBottom) - 50

    # bottom = (height - distFromBottom) + 200

    # calculate the ratio for all of the edges

    left = relativeLeft*width

    right = relativeRight*width

    top = relativeTop*height

    bottom = relativeBottom*height

    # left = width / 5

    # top = height - (height / 3)

    # right = 4 * width /5

    # bottom = height

    # crop the image

    im1 = im.crop((left, top-(height/5), right, bottom))

 

    im1.save(pngLocation)

My objective here was to scroll to the target location, (found by using a user input date). Then, finding the location and size of the box (3 rows) I am trying to capture. Then, finding where it is located relative to the window size. Then, after the screenshot, cropping the screenshot using ratios for each of the edges of the box compared to the edge of the window that was screenshotted.
This works for my laptop (probably because I designed and tested it on there), but even in that case, I was running into an issue where the length of the html was not longer than the window. Thus, I added the
if bodyHeight < windowHeight:

        relativeTop = float((windowHeight -rowYPos)) / float(windowHeight)

        relativeBottom = float((windowHeight -rowYPos) + rowHeight) / float(windowHeight)

    else:

        relativeTop = float((windowHeight - (bodyHeight-rowYPos))) / float(windowHeight)

        relativeBottom = float((windowHeight - (bodyHeight-rowYPos)) + rowHeight) / float(windowHeight)

However, this still didn't fix that issue either. I am able to reliably find the object and identify its edges every time, but the screenshot still varies by monitor.
Overall, I am wondering if I am wasting my time trying to do this contextual screenshot, and if it is even possible given different website layouts for different screens.
